# How to enforce SAX parser to not transform XML entities?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser

I'm using SAX for parsing large xml file.
But it transforms every [XML code](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) to it's symbol version.

How to prevent SAX this behaviour.

Example `with_amp.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <title>One Two</title>
  <title>One &amp;mdash;  Two</title>
</root>
```

python handler:

```
from xml.sax import handler, parse

class Handler(handler.ContentHandler):
    def characters(self, content):
        if content.isspace(): return
        print(content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse(open('with_amp.xml', 'r'), Handler())
```

I want the output to be:

```
One Two
One &amp;mdash;  Two
```

Comment: It only decodes XML entities (`&amp;`, `&lt;` and `&gt;`) actually. The `&mdash;` entity is not recognized (not a legal entity unless defined by a DTD).

Comment: Yes, but I want to prevent this entities decoding.

Answer (score 1):

Using saxutils, I managed to do it. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.utils.html#module-xml.sax.saxutils

e.g. with your info :

```
print(content)
```

will become

```
print(saxutils.escape(content))
```

(you will need to add saxutils to your imports though :
the whole will then be

```
from xml.sax import handler, parse, saxutils

class Handler(handler.ContentHandler):
    def characters(self, content):
        if content.isspace(): return
        print(saxutils.escape(content))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse(open('with_amp.xml', 'r'), Handler())
```